# Close/Quit All Screens with SSH

Tags: ssh, bash, gnu-screen

I have a lot of screens on my server. With `screen -ls` I get:

```
 There are screens on:
    12858.test1 (Detached)
    28210.test2 (Detached)
    12494.moretesting3  (Detached)
    31787.testingfour4  (Detached)
    13192.testscreen5   (Detached)
5 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

I know I can quit an individual screen with `screen -S 12858 -X quit` or `screen -S test1 -X quit` but I need a way to close all the screens at the same time.

Is there an ssh command or bash script that is able to close every open/detached screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would a simple `killall screen` suffice?

Comment: ...as long as you're not on a system where `killall` is the SysV style tool that literally kills *all* processes you can kill. (Of course as long as you're not root this will probably have the desired effect - all your screen sessions will be gone :-)

Comment: What if you are root? Is there anything else that would work?

Comment: You can also do `kill \`pidof screen\``

Answer (score -2):

For that very reason, I recommend using byobu.  It's in most Linux Distros' repo's, and it is much easier to have multiple screens open at once and see them all at a glance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's asking about how to easily kill off a bunch of detached screen sessions, not about how to  have multiple screens open.

Comment: But, using byobu makes this very easy since it will show if you on login if existing / multiple sessions are open, and allow you to kill any/all of them.